# Google TV to Dell monitor

Tags: display

I have a Google TV which is connected to a Dell monitor. The image works but there is no sound. Is there a adapter that we could use to get sound?

Answer (score 0):

In no way am I promoting this product, but is this something that you can use? [HDMI to VGA Audio Converter](http://www.vvdeals.com/products/HDMI-to-VGA-and-3-5mm-Audio-Converter-Apple-TV-Google-TV-Compatible_41.html)